# Why isn't my Python script returning the page source properly?

Tags: python, url, urllib2

I just wrote a script that is meant to go through the alphabet and find all unclaimed four-letter twitter names (really just for practice as I'm new to Python). I have written a couple previous scripts that use 'urllib2' to get website html from a url, but this time it doesn't appear to be working. Here is my script:

```
import urllib2

src=''
url=''
print "finding four-letter @usernames on twitter..."
d_one=''
d_two=''
d_three=''
d_four=''
n_one=0
n_two=0
n_three=0
n_four=0
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

while (n_one > 26):
    while(n_two > 26):
        while (n_three > 26):
            while (n_four > 26):
                d_one=letters[n_one]
                d_two=letters[n_two]
                d_three=letters[n_three]
                d_four=letters[n_four]
                url = "twitter.com/" + d_one + d_two + d_three + d_four

                src=urllib2.urlopen(url)
                src=src.read()
                if (src.find('Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!') >= 0):
                    print "nope"
                    n_four+=1
                else:
                    print url
                    n_four+=1
            n_three+=1
            n_four=0
        n_two+=1
        n_three=0
        n_four=0
    n_one+=1    
    n_two=0
    n_three=0
    n_four=0
```

Running this code returned the following error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file name.py on line 29,
>   but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html
>   for details

and after visiting that link and doing some additional searching, I added the following line to the top of the document:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Now, while it no longer returns an error, nothing appears to be happening. I added the line

```
print src
```

which should have printed the html of each url, but nothing happened when I ran it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is/was line 29? Obviously the code above does not represent your real code - otherweise we would see special chars in your code above. Downvote...

Comment: line 29 was "print 'nope'"... I swear I just wrote this script five minutes ago...

Comment: Just for your information, this script will take a really long time to run. There are `26*26*26*26 = 456976` possible four-letter words. Even if you're able to process two per second, your script is still going to take `456976 * 0.5seconds * (1minute/60seconds) * (1hour/60minutes) = approximately 63.47 hours`.

Comment: Thank you, and yes I know. I will run it in intervals (first until n_one > 5, and I will slowly increase this number). It was more for practice than anything, but I appreciate the thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you initialise `n_one=0`, and then do a loop `while (n_one > 26)`. When Python first encounters it, it sees `while (0 > 26)` which is obviously false and it therefore skips the entire loop.

And as gnibbler's answer tells you, there are cleaner ways of doing the loop anyway.

Comment: Wow. You're completely right – they should have been "<" not ">." Thank you so much for pointing that out and for the quick help.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the excessive nesting by using `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
for d_one, d_two, d_three, d_four in product(letters, repeat=4):
    ...
```

Instead of defining a list of letters, you could just use `strings.ascii_lowercase`

You should tell urlopen which protocol you are using (http)

```
url = "http://twitter.com/" + d_one + d_two + d_three + d_four
```

Also when you *do* get a page that doesn't exist, urlopen raises a `404`, so you should be checking for that instead of looking at the page text

Comment: Oh great! Thank you for the tip; I will implement this.